# Angular - How to get an HTML element inside the *ngFor directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't get the "box-message" class using "document.querySelectorAll('.box-message')" inside a tree where the "*ngFor" directive is used.

I am making an "http rest" request, after the request the "*ngFor" directive completes the building of the house and after that I am trying to get the "box-message" class using "document.querySelectorAll('.box-message')".

But as I understand it (but I could be wrong), the house does not have time to be built, and that is why I do not receive the “box-message” class.

I tried using AfterViewInit but it doesn't help.

How to solve this problem?

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="ul-ads">
      <li class="li-ads" *ngFor="let ads of ads">
        <div class="box-message">{{ads.message}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
        export class AdsComponent implements OnInit {


          ads!: Ads[];



          public getAds(): Observable<any> {

            return this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:8080/apis/data/ads`,
              {observe: 'response'});

          }


          ngOnInit(): void {


            this.getAds().subscribe({

              next: data => {

                this.ads = responseData.body.content;

                const boxMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.box-message');
                console.log(boxMessage) // NodeList[]

              }


            });


          }


        }
```

[image]

Comment: The question is why you need to get the list  ? i mean there is no need to do that. And that is not going along with how you should use angular. 
The only reason of doing so would be for testing purposes and for that there is appropriate functions in angular testing. But you can try to add cnageDetectorRef.detectChanges before queriing.

Comment: I have added a picture. Look here please.
I need to get the "box-message" class because these are buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage ViewChildren to accomplish this.

In your template. add a reference for each box message:

```html
<ul class="ul-ads">
  <li class="li-ads" *ngFor="let ads of ads">
     <div #boxMessage class="box-message">{{ads.message}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your component, add a property to hold the view children and subscribe to the `changes` observable:

```js
@ViewChildren('boxMessage')
boxMessages: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.boxMessages.changes.subscribe(boxMessage => {
    // your code here
  });
}
```

Any time the view children are changed, your code will execute **after** the children are rendered.

*There's no need to use setTimeout to introduce an artificial delay.*

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need "wait" Angular repaint. Generally You use a setTimeout without miliseconds.

```
...
next: data => {
    this.ads = responseData.body.content;
    setTimeout(()=>{
       const boxMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.box-message');
       console.log(boxMessage) // NodeList[]
       console.log(this.ads.message) // to print data 
    })
  }
```

Think that angular execute the instructions under subscribe and then repaint. It's the reason you not get the elements.

IMPORTANT: In Angular rarely we need use the old javascript way document.getElementBy. You can declare ViewChildren using a template reference variable

```
   <ul class="ul-ads">
      <li class="li-ads" *ngFor="let ads of ads">
        <!--see the #item-->
        <div #item class="box-message">{{ads.message}}</div>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Then you can get all of them in a QueryList

```
@ViewChildren('item') items!:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

See that in an elementRef, the `nativeElement` property is the html tag

A [Query list](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) allow convert to Array, reorder, get the first and last element, subscribe to changes...

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
     this.items.changes.subscribe(_=>{
         console.log(this.items.first.nativeElement)
         console.log(this.items.last.nativeElement)
         //the third element
         const htmlElement=this.items.find((_,index)=>index==2)?.nativeElement
         ...

     })
}
```